# Set asp:CustomValidator text from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator, requiredfieldvalidator

I have User ID and Password fields, both of which work well with the RequiredFieldValidator. Just below that, I have placed a CustomValidator, and I'm attempting to have a similar validation from the codebehind when the passwords don't match.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="PWRequired"   
    ControlToValidate="PasswordTextbox"  
    Display="None"  
    ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />A password is required." />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="PWMatch"
    ControlToValidate="PasswordTextbox"  
    Display="None"
    ErrorMessage="<b>Password is Invalid</b><br />Please enter a valid password." />
<AjaxControl:ValidatorCalloutExtender 
    runat="Server"
    ID="PWValidationExtender"
    TargetControlID="PWRequired" 
    Width="185px"
    WarningIconImageUrl="/Images/warning.gif" />
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextbox" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

(Hopefully that formatted correctly. I've never gotten the "4 space" thing to work.

Then in the codebehind, when the PWs don't match, I'm trying this:

```
CustomValidator myValidator = (CustomValidator)this.FindControl("PWMatch");
myValidator.Text = "<b>Password is Invalid</b><br />Please enter a valid password."; 
ValidatorCalloutExtender myValExtender = (ValidatorCalloutExtender)this.FindControl("PWValidationExtender");
myValExtender.ID = "PWValidationExtender";
myValExtender.TargetControlID="PWMatch";
myValExtender.WarningIconImageUrl = "/Images/warning.gif";
myValExtender.Width = new Unit(250);
```

I hope it is something simple and silly that I'm missing. I've burned a whole day trying to figure this out.

Thanks in advance for your help.

=========================================================================

Thanks freefaller.  I've tried that and get "no joy."  So, I'm coming at it from a little different direction.

I've changed to a CompareValidator, like this: (again, hope the markup works)

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="PWCompareValidator"
    ControlToValidate="PasswordTextbox"
    Operator="Equal"
    ValueToCompare="<%# GetPassword() %>"
    Text="<b>Password is Invalid</b><br />Please enter a valid password."
    Type="String" />
```

It's giving me a message, but always evaluating to "false" because the GetPassword method is not being called.  If I keep hammering at this, I think I can get it to work, but if you see a quick solution, I'm all ears.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.Text` use `.ErrorMessage`

So change...

```
myValidator.Text = "<b>Password is Invalid</b><br />Please enter a valid password.";
```

To...

```
myValidator.ErrorMessage = "<b>Password is Invalid</b><br />Please enter a valid password.";
```

---

**Update** (due to update in question)

The `CompareValidator` is designed to compare two values on the actual website... the `ValueToCompare` is supposed to be a static value, and by placing the password into it, you are opening up a security hole (because you'll be potentially sending the password to the browser - although I have doubts that `ValueToCompare="<%# GetPassword() %>"` will actually work in the first place.)

The `CustomValidator` requires you to provide at least one handler... definitely one on the server (using the `OnServerValidate` attribute), and if necessary one on the browser (using the `ClientValidationFunction` attribute).  It is within the handlers that you must set the `IsValid` attribute of the `args` parameter according the result of your checks.

(I say "definitely one on the server" because client-side script is easy to get around, so you always want to have something on the server to catch anybody trying.)

It isn't 100% clear exactly what you're trying to do, or indeed exactly what you've currently got in place, so it's difficult to give you any direct advice other than what I have above.

---

**Final Update**

As you are trying to check a password, here is an example of what I think you need...

```
Password: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqPassword"
   ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Provide Password" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusPassword"
   ControlToValidator="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Incorrect Password"
   OnServerValidate="cusPassword_ServerValidate"/>
```

Then in your code-behind, you need to have the handler

```
protected void cusPassword_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  args.IsValid = (txtPassword.Text == GetPassword());
}
```

Comment: Thanks freefaller.  I've tried that and get "no joy."  So, I'm coming at it from a little different direction.  I added the new approach to the original posting above.

Comment: @DJGrey - have you actually got any handlers on your custom validators?  Either server-side or client-side?

Comment: freefaller - sorry for my ignorance.  Novice coder here.  What do you mean by "handler?"  I suspect you mean something to capture and display what the validator returns.  The error message IS now displaying, but the GetPassword() method in the CodeBehind is not being called.  I suspect if I can get a string return value from that method, that my CompareEvaluator will work.  Is this a valid approach?

Comment: The handler is the piece of code that is called when the system want to validate. It is required when you call a `CustomValidator` because it doesn't know what you want to do, you have to tell it! Also, unless you're dealing with template based controls (such as `Repeater`, `GridView`) you cannot use code-blocks on attributes to asp controls (i.e. you cannot have `<asp:Text Text="<%#GetText()%>"/>`).  That is why `GetPassword()` is not being called - if you look at the HTML sent to the browser you would probably find the static string of `GetPassword()` in there

Comment: LOL!!  What I'm wanting to do:

I have server-side UserID/Password validation, but have never been pleased with the error messages returned when it fails.  It's just ugly.  Yesterday, I stumbled across the ValidationExtender that pops up an attractive balloon.  It works beautifully with the RequiredFieldValidator, so I wanted to do the same thing with an invalid password, invalid UserID, and user that is valid but not yet approved for login.  When those error conditions appear, I am hopeful that I can pop up a little balloon just like the RequiredFieldValidator does.

Does that help?

Comment: @DJGrey, unfortunately I know nothing about `ValidationExtender` so I can't help there. If it has the ability to check the validation on the server side, then yes it would probably be possible... however what you certainly don't want to do is have any client-side checking that involved sending the current password to the client (for obvious security reasons).  Sorry if my lack of knowledge of the control is wasting your time

Comment: No, no, no!!  You're a Rock Star!!  I really appreciate the help.  I'm going to try the approach you mentioned above.  I'll post back here with the results.

Comment: Tally-Ho!!  Sweet.  This works.  I can now find a way to tie it to the extender to get the little "balloon" effect.  Thanks again freefaller.  You have been very helpful and instructive.

Comment: Cool - really glad I could have helped @DJGray (I've only just noticed I've been spelling the "Gray" part of your name incorrectly - apologies for that).  Good luck with the rest of your project, and thanks for the "best answer" mark  :-)